# 2d correlation of two similar parts

Tags: python, computer-vision, mle, flann, ransac

I have to solve the following problem:

I have two images with the same part, but the part is rotated, scaled and translated in the second image (without shear). This part has  characteristic points that you can use to compare one with each other.

The problem is: The second part can contain one or more errors (not too many).

I need to compute the rotation, scaling and translation matrix (this is not the problem itself) so thus the characteristic points of the first image have the minimum accumulated distance with the points of the second image.

I'm working with python, but the first approximation is brute-force and I get the minimum distance from each `im1` point to `im2` point. Is it possible to do this with `ransac` or `flann`? What is the best or correct way to approach it? I think is a MLE problem, and the function to minimize is the accumulated distance to every pair of points.

Later, I will assign to each `image1` characteristic point the nearest `image2` point, because if it's not clear, until now we don't know what the correspondence is.

Comment: It is always best to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: yes;  at least, please provide examples of the two images